# Robot Framework - Keywords after [Return] line are also executing

Tags: robotframework

Set of instructions which are written after [Return] statement are getting executed. Robot Framework should through an error or should not consider the keywords written after [Return] keyword. Please give explanation if I missed something.

```
Settings

Variables

Keywords
Custom Keyword
[Return] hyyyy
Return From Keyword hyyyy2222

Test Cases
Test1
${var_rt_ky2}= Custom Keyword
Log To Console ${var_rt_ky2}
```

Output:
hyyyy2222

In other case

```
Settings

Variables

Keywords
Custom Keyword
Return From Keyword hyyyy2222
[Return] hyyyy

Test Cases
Test1
${var_rt_ky2}= Custom Keyword
Log To Console ${var_rt_ky2}
```

Output:
hyyyy

Answer (score 2):

This is how robot is designed to work. `[return]` merely defines the return value, it doesn't cause the keyword to return when it is called.

If you want to explicitly return from a function you need to use one of the keywords from the built-in library (e.g. [Return from keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword) or [Return from keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Return%20From%20Keyword%20If), etc. )

Comment: Thank you @Bryan - RobotFramework officials have replied in the community forum - https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3214 that they are going to update the documentation at this moment as we don't have this info in the document.